# Change width of element after some height

Tags: html, css

My question is simple - is this layout possible? I attached some code and how it should look like. It has a menu with categories on one side and products on the other. When `div` with categories ends, products' `div` should fill all the width below.
Dividing `#products` into two separate `div`s isn't a good idea for me, because for example height of `#menu` can be 1,5 row with pictures.

[image]

```
<style>
    #menu {
        ???
    }
    #products {
        ???
    }
</style>
<section class="container">
    <div id="menu">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="products">
        <img src....>
        ...more images
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can approach this using `CSS Grid`.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.product {
  background-color: gray;
}

.menu,
.product {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>  
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbx5zL82/2/)

Comment: OP - Just note that based on your question you may need to have some JS to adjust the menu size/the menu's css property 'grid-row-end', if as you say it's dynamic.